# Row Range Find specific value populate new cell with column header

Tags: row, range, cell

I have a spread sheet with rows in it that have depreciating values (G3:AJ3).
These represent 30 years of values with a year at the top of each column (Y1, Y2, ..., Y30).
Example of Row 3 = 76.02, 75.48, 73.24, 72.89, 71.19, 70.39, 69.42, 67.55, 66.24, ...

What I would like to do for each row is find out when the value in each row reaches 70 (expression would be cell > 69.5 and Cell < 70.49) (for example L3), The populate E3 with the year this happens (Row Header value in L1 for cell L3).

I would like to repeat this for each row, in this case Row 3 to Row 512.

Answer (score 0):

I am actually looking to do almost the exact same thing... I'm still investigating the solution... Hoping someone will answer this one... If I find something, I'll post it here...